# Any experience with replacing BOOST_FOREACH by range-based for loop from C++11?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, c++11

Did you ever went through the process of replacing the `BOOST_FOREACH` by the range-based `for` loop? Are there any gotchas when doing it *mechanically* (i.e. not doing a deep study of the code around).

Background: I do have sources with about 250K lines, compiled with Microsoft VC++ 10 (Visual Studio 2010). The code uses also BOOST_FOREACH from the boost library. I am just trying the VC++ 11 (Visual Studio 2012 RC) that implements also the range-based `for` loop with the `auto`.

So far, I have met the situation where the element was declared outside the `BOOST_FOREACH` (no declaration in the parentheses):

```
BOOST_FOREACH (element, container) {
    ...
}
```

... and the `element` was expected to have the value set in the loop after the `break`. Can you remember similar *problems*?

When the `BOOST_FOREACH` contains the declaration, would you choose to replace the explicit type by `auto`? Is there any advantage to do so when one just mechanically rewrites the `BOOST_FOREACH` instead of leaving the explicit declaration there?

Thanks for your help,
  Petr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage of `auto` over using the actual type or reference type is that the code will continue to work if the container type changes.  This may not be what you want if you're intentionally performing a type conversion on the result of indirecting the container iterator.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (int i: v) ...
```

If `v` changes to `std::vector<long>` or `std::vector<unsigned>` then the type conversion may be unwanted; still, a compiler warning should catch this (especially for a narrowing conversion).  On the other hand, you could have code where a (widening) conversion is intended:

```
std::vector<char> v;
for (int i: v) ...
```

Comment: Well, I understand that `auto` is the winner when a new code is entered -- as your write. However, I feel a bit more secure when leaving the explicit type not replaced by `auto`. Firstly, it would take more effort, and secondly, I could introduce a human error when editing. (There is a lot of the `BOOST_FOREACH`, and I am not able to look at the code around for each case.) Anyway, would you consider my decision to keep the explicit data type in the new `for` loops as not-problematic?

Comment: @pepr I'd agree that keeping the explicit type will usually be the best option; you'll need to be aware of it if changing container types later.

Answer (score 1):

> would you choose to replace the explicit type by auto?

Yes, but if the type is e.g. `int&` then I would replace it with `auto&` otherwise the deduced type will not be a reference.

Comment: I do not consider the `&` being part of the `auto` as the element of any data type can be accessed or via value or via reference. My question could be precised whether I can get any advantage caused by *replacing the explicit data type by `auto`*. Better to say, if the replacement of the `BOOST_FOREACH` can be done via a regular expression in the IDE, whether it makes sense to spend the time with extra replacement of the type by `auto`.

Comment: The main advantage is if you later change the container type, with `auto` you don't need to update the loop variable. You could save your time and leave code that works with explicit types, there's nothing wrong with that choice.